# CUDA equivalent of estimateRigidTransform in OpenCV 3

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm working on a video stabilisation project using OpenCV, and I've got a CPU implementation working but the performance needs improvement so I'm trying to move most of the processing to the GPU.

The current implementation primarily uses these four OpenCV functions:

- `cv::goodFeaturesToTrack`
- `cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`
- `cv::estimateRigidTransform`
- `cv::warpAffine`

So far I've found the following equivalents on the GPU:

- `cv::cuda::createGoodFeaturesToTrackDetector`
- `cv::cuda::SparsePyrLKOpticalFlow`
- `cv::cuda::warpAffine`

Is there a CUDA equivalent of `estimateRigidTransform`?

Comment: I'm not sure that you want one. It should be pretty fast on cpu, and overhead to loading it to GPU can make it slower for low count of points. estimateRigidTransform uses least squares method, which can be computed using cuda cuSolver. It shouldn't be hard to implement if you really want it on GPU

Comment: Hey @taarraas thanks for the comment. I'm re-writing the video stabilisation to be 100% on the GPU, so I don't want to have to download/upload the points to run `estimateRigidTransform` on the CPU. If there's no existing implementation on the GPU then I'll write it in CUDA, just thought I'd ask in case I had missed something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV doesn't have implementation for estimateRigidTransform on CUDA. 
There is opencv based project on github, which has functions for computing homographies and estimating rigid transforms: https://github.com/danielsuo/cuSIFT

Here is function you need:
https://github.com/danielsuo/cuSIFT/blob/master/extras/rigidTransform.cu